# Post Request to Django Rest APIView lacking user (token authentication)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm creating API for Twitter like app in Django and since I implemented token authentication (rest-auth) I have problem with creating new tweets as it throws:

```py
{
    "author": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

I've tried CreateAPIView:

```py
class TweetCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = TweetModelSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    # I've also tried to add the author field mannualy
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user)
```

but it didn't work so I created custom post method:

```py
class TweetCreateAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def post(self, request, format=None):

        serializer = TweetModelSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(author=request.user)

            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response(serializer.errors,  status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

but it still can't identify the user creating the tweet

Model:

```py
class Tweet(models.Model):

    retweeted_by = models.ManyToManyField(
        TwitterUser, blank=True, related_name='retweets')

    commented_tweet = models.ManyToManyField(
        'self', related_name='comments', blank=True, symmetrical=False)

    author = models.ForeignKey(
        TwitterUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tweets')

    content = models.CharField(max_length=280)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    liked_by = models.ManyToManyField(
        TwitterUser, blank=True, related_name='likes')

    objects = TweetManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content

    def get_comments(self):
        comments = Tweet.objects.filter(commented_tweet__pk=self.pk)
        return comments

    def get_retweets(self):
        retweets = TwitterUser.retweets(tweet__id=self.id)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('tweets:pk', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Serializer:

```py
class TweetModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    likes_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    already_liked = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_likes_count(self, tweet):
        return tweet.liked_by.all().count()

    def get_already_liked(self, tweet):
        user = None
        request = self.context.get("request")

        if request and hasattr(request, "user"):
            user = request.user

        if user is not None:
            if user in tweet.liked_by.all():
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            pass

    class Meta:
        model = Tweet
        fields = [
            'id',
            'author',
            'commented_tweet',
            'content',
            'retweeted_by',
            'likes_count',
            'already_liked',
            'created_at',
        ]
```

Settings:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # 3rd party
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_auth',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'channels',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'rest_auth.registration',
    'reset_migrations',
    'corsheaders',

]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS':     'twitter.paginations.StandardResultsSetPagination',
    'TEST_REQUEST_DEFAULT_FORMAT': 'json',
}
```

Authentication itself works fine, including registration, so I don't think that it's a problem with tokens, yet I have no other idea where the bug is when even CreateAPIView doesn't work.

Comment: First of all use a `ModelViewSet` to easily provide API endpoints for your models.
But the actual error in your Serializer, you need an additional attribute `read_only_fields = ('author', )`. Let me know if it fixes the error, I will add a detailed answer.

Comment: @VaibhavVishal Yes, works fine. I didn't use ModelViewSet as I've just started with django so I wanted to play around with code and write some custom methods.

Comment: thats cool.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your serializer you have `author` in the list of fields. Since it's a `ModelSerializer`, drf is picking up details for that field from the model, and in the model author is `null = False` by default, hence drf is making it a required field, since it can't be null. But since you want the author to be automatically the user who is making the request, you don't need that field to be editable. Hence make it a read only field in your serializer like this:

```
class TweetModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    class Meta:
        model = Tweet
        fields = ('id', 'author', 'commented_tweet', 'content', 'retweeted_by',
                  'likes_count', 'already_liked', 'created_at', )
        read_only_fields = ('author', )  # it's read only now, so drf go looking for it in POST data
```

Now you just need to override the `perform_create` method, no need to change the post method.

If you need even more customizations like `superuser` can edit authors but no one else, you can override the `__init__` method your serializer and make fields read_only based on `request.user` which gets a bit complicated.

Also, you should consider using `tuple` instead of `list` for `fields` and `read_only_fields` to get minor performance boost.

Comment: Thank you for help!